# Lambda Statement that selects all child that match criteria

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I have a data structure as listed below.  How do I get the children of the children that meet the criteria?

I have a list of Adults that contain a list of children.

- AdultJoe

  - ChildJoe Age 12
  - ChildJane Age 10
- AdultFrancis

  - ChildTom Age 12
  - ChildTony Age 10

Using the above data structure how do I get all of the child that are age 12?

This is what I've tried and it's not doing what I need.

```
Adults.Where(Function(adult) adult.Children.Any(Function(child) child.age= 12))
```

Comment: it doesnt filter the existing list,  but returns a new one with the subset

Comment: Sorry I missed something in my lambda statement.  I added adult.children.any.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "flatten" an IEnumerable of IEnumerables, use SelectMany:

```
Dim children = Adults.SelectMany(Function(a) a.Children).Where(Function(c) c.Age = 12)
```

This is implicit in the LINQ syntax:

```
Dim children = from adult in Adults
               from child in adult.Children
               where child.Age = 12
               select child
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for.   The added Linq statement was nice add as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't describe your classes, but assuming that the adults have a `Children` property, you could use something like this:

```
Dim twelveYearOlds = adults.SelectMany(
    Function(adult) adult.Children
).Where(
    Function(child) child.Age = 12
)
```

The `SelectMany` gives you a list of all the children of all the adults, and the where filters that list to the 12-year-olds.

Comment: Yeah, what Jerry said (missed it by 30 seconds!).

Comment: Wish my question could have 2 answers.  Thank yo for the answer.